# Get an object from an array of objects with the highest value of a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]

0: Object { plName: "player1", plNumber: 1, score: 30, … }
1: Object { plName: "player2", plNumber: 2, score: 24, … }
2: Object { plName: "player3", plNumber: 3, score: 89, … }
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get an object with the highest value of the score property. In this case:

```
2: Object { plName: "player3", plNumber: 3, score: 89, … }
```

I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: what if you have two or more of highest scores? have you tried something? what goes wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A simple reduce should do it.

```js
let arr = [{
    plName: "player1",
    plNumber: 1,
    score: 30
  },
  {
    plName: "player2",
    plNumber: 2,
    score: 24
  },
  {
    plName: "player3",
    plNumber: 3,
    score: 89
  }
];

let result = arr.reduce((o1, o2) => o1.score > o2.score ? o1 : o2);
console.log(result);
```

If there could be multiple high score

```js
let arr = [{
    plName: "player1",
    plNumber: 1,
    score: 30
  },
  {
    plName: "player2",
    plNumber: 2,
    score: 24
  },
  {
    plName: "player3",
    plNumber: 3,
    score: 89
  },
  {
    plName: "player4",
    plNumber: 4,
    score: 24
  },
  {
    plName: "player5",
    plNumber: 5,
    score: 89
  }
];

let maxScoreObject = arr.reduce((o1, o2) => o1.score > o2.score ? o1 : o2);
let result = arr.filter(o => o.score === maxScoreObject.score);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic function could be something like

```js
const data = [{
    plName: "player1",
    plNumber: 1,
    score: 30
  },
  {
    plName: "player2",
    plNumber: 2,
    score: 24
  },
  {
    plName: "player3",
    plNumber: 3,
    score: 89
  }
];


function maxBy(array, property) {
  return array.reduce((max, item) => {
    if (item[property] > max[property]) return item;
    return max;
  })
}

console.log(maxBy(data, 'score'));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Sort the objects in *descending* order from biggest to smallest *`score`*, get the first one which is the maximum score.

```js
data.sort((a,b)=>b.score-a.score)[0]
//{plName: 'player3', plNumber: 3, score: 89}
```

Comment: Though it looks short, or same as reduce operator, its a lot more processing than any other solution, should be discouraged to be used for this particular scenario.